# Lumia unresponsive after Windows Device Recovery Tool 3.11 error

Tags: lumia, recovery-tool

I have a Lumia 930 with Windows 10 mobile. I was trying to reset it to Windows Phone 8.1 using the Windows Device Recovery tool v3.11.34101. It detected the phone, and gave me the option of downloading the OS, which I did. After it finished downloading, it gave back a random error (which I was dumb enough to not check it) and the phone just turned off.

Can't turn it back on: it won't even vibrate or show any light. Windows Says it's a "Unknown Device" and Windows Device Recovery Tool won't detect it.

Shall I assume it's just gone, or is anything I could do still?

Comment: I suggest asking this one also at Superuser Stack Exchange, since this question goes beyond the software (Windows Phone). Repairing (if possible) should come from the hardware side.

Comment: Followed you advice and created question 1234575 in superuser.com :)